# Magento2 - How to create a new Page Layout

Tags: php, magento2, page-layouts

I'm attempting to create a new page layout for Categories, here's what I have so far:

**app/code/Karl/Subcategories/registration.php**

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Karl_Subcategories', __DIR__);
```

**app/code/Karl/Subcategories/etc/module.xml**

```
<config>
    <module name="Karl_Subcategories" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Karl/Subcategories/view/frontend/layouts.xml**

```
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="subcategories">
        <label translate="true">Subcategories</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

So far this is working, I now have a new option within the dropdown for "Custom Design > Page Layout".

But I'm having difficulty trying to define the actual page template which should be used and I'm unable to find much documentation on this.

**app/code/Karl/Subcategories/view/frontend/page_layouts/subcategories.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Karl_Subcategories::subcategories.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

**app/code/Karl/Subcategories/view/frontend/templates/subcategories.phtml**

```
<?php
echo 'hi';
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have keep subcategories.xml file inside `app/code/Karl/Subcategories/view/frontend/page_layout` folder. May be you have mistakes in `folder name page_layout not page_layouts`. 
plz check using above folder name and try again.

Comment: It's definitely supposed to be `layouts.xml` not `layout.xml` and `page_layouts` not `page_layout` because if I change these the option disappears from the dropdown, although it doesn't look like it's hitting the `subcategories.xml` file.

Comment: have you keep folder name page_layout?

Comment: Yes, tried both `page_layout` and `page_layouts`

Comment: you have to keep layouts.xml and page_layout/subcategories.xml file and try.

Comment: I have, still doesn't work.